# HTTP request wait times 10 seconds for some static assets

Tags: performance, amazon-web-services, vue.js, https, page-load-time

I recently deployed my sites to a new infrastructure in AWS.

I have a vue.js app that now sometimes takes a long time to load because some static assets are stuck waiting for 10 seconds.

It's always an asset, either JS, json, or an image. The wait time is almost always exactly 10.1 seconds.

**Waterfall chart of page download**
[image: Waterfall chart of page download]

[image: Waterfall chart of page download]

A bit more about the setup:

1. Running Linux 18.0.4 on EC2
2. Apache 2.4.29
3. Hostname in route53 is going through an application lb in AWS

It's likely a configuration somewhere, but I am stumped and don't know where to look.

Comment: From where you are serving your files?

Comment: The files are being served from the EC2 running apache.

Comment: Had a thought last night, that it could be the ELB bouncing between instances. I have turned on stickiness to see if that helps.

Comment: Hitting multiple instances behind the ELB shouldn't cause any delays.

Comment: Confirmed. that didn't help.